# What is the significance of a period (.) in domain names?

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

[image]

The above image shows the output of a DNS response message using dig command .
Why is there a period (.) after .com (**like com.** )

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. Copy the text instead. [SF] has all the formatting features needed to properly format the copied text.

Answer (score 6):

A dot at the end of a domain name signifies the DNS root.  If you don't specify the dot, a DNS resolver could append it's default domain to the domain you provided.  For example, if you query `example.org`, the result could return `example.org.example.com.` (`example.com.` being the default domain). But, if you query `example.org.` a dns resolver would always return `example.org.`.

Answer (score 2):

"." alone means "DNS root domain" which is served by well-known DNS root servers, whose addresses are shipped with OS. They will reply with NS records for TLD servers, and so on.

"." at the end of domain name means "absolute address". Domain name without dot mean "relative name". What really means depends on the context.

1. In the user environment context, you have so called "DNS suffix", configured into system resolver. It could be received with DHCP, too. There could be several suffices configured; the resolver first tries to append them to the actual relative query and resolve that; it will threat relative query as absoulte only if it didn't find anything when appending suffices.

In Linux, that suffix configured as "search" option in /etc/resolv.conf. In Windows, you can view them with ipconfig /all and update in "computer identity" dialog (together with local system name, AD domain or some workgroup participation and so on).

So, nslookup domain.com will first try to resolve domain.com.local.suffix., and query domain.com. only if first one didn't found.

2. In the context of zone file, dot at the end is a syntax element. When you write zone file for BIND, you will have an ORIGIN set, either implicitly (as you configured zone name) or explicitly, with "$ORIGIN some.name.tld" directive. All names without dot are then treated as if they have that origin appended.

For example consider this part of zone file:

```
$ORIGIN foo-bar.com.
www         A         1.2.3.4
example.com A         2.1.3.4
xam         CNAME     www
exam        CNAME     example.com
alam        CNAME     example.com.
```

This part is equivalent to this expanded one:

```
$ORIGIN .
www.foo-bar.com.         A         1.2.3.4
example.com.foo-bar.com. A         2.1.3.4
xam.foo-bar.com.         CNAME     www.foo-bar.com.
exam.foo-bar.com.        CNAME     example.com.foo-bar.com.
alam.foo-bar.com.        CNAME     example.com.
```

Notice it appended origin in every place without dot and din't appended origin in the last CNAME record, because there was an already absolute name.